# How to scrape Ask engine search results using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I created a spider to scrape Ask search results from a set of user-defined keywords. But, whenever I run the command `scrapy crawl pageSearch -o test.json` this creates an empty test.json file for me, I don't know why. To create this api, I was inspired by a developer  [page](https://dev-to.translate.goog/iankerins/scraping-millions-of-google-serps-the-easy-way-python-scrapy-spider-4hpc?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc) that showed how to scrape google SERPs and also the tutorial from the official scrapy  [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#intro-tutorial). Here is a git of what I get from the command [line](https://gist.github.com/gouneken/f6b7e9775e2d1372d994006a133f5109). I searched for the solution from stack Overflow questions but without success. I believed from the following command prompt line:`'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware'` that it was an http error, but after searching the internet it was not and according to my terminal my robot ran successfully and the url address that I specified in my code where the scraping was to take place is valid. And personally, I don't see my mistake so I'm lost. Here is my code :

```
import scrapy
import json
import datetime


class PagesearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pageSearch'

    def start_requests(self):
        queries = [ 'love']
        for query in queries:
            url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?q='+query
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})

    def parse(self, response):
           print(response.text)
           di = json.loads(response.text)
           pos = response.meta['pos']
           dt = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
           for result in di['organic_results']:
               title = result['a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link']
               snippet = result['p.PartialSearchResults-item-abstract']
               link = result['div.PartialSearchResults-item-url']
               item = {'title': title, 'snippet': snippet, 'link': link, 'position': pos, 'date': dt}
               pos += 1
               yield item

               next_page = di['pagination']['nextPageUrl']
               if next_page:
                   yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': pos})

                   #scrapy crawl pageSearch -o test.json
```

I use Windows 10. Also, I ask for your help, thank you!

Comment: The url you are trying to scrape is invalid. Try to replace `url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?q='+query` with `url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?o=0&l=dir&qo=serpSearchTopBox&q=' + query`

Comment: Also your selectors are not correct. The data is not returned as json

Comment: did you run it in console to see errors. It shows error because server sends `HTML`, not `JSON` - but you use `json.loads(response.text)`. You have to use scrapy functions to search in `HTML` in `response` (instead of `response.text`)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: your output shows that URL `https://www.ask.com/web?q=love'` was skiped because file `robots.txt` doesn't allow to scrape it. See `[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.ask.com/web?q=love>`. And you have to turn off this middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two problems:

---

**First:**

In your output you can see

```
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.ask.com/web?q=love>
```

which means it reads https://www.ask.com/robots.txt and there is rule

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /web
```

and scrapy respects it and it skips url `https://www.ask.com/web?q=love`

You have to set `ROBOTTXT_OBEY = False` in your settings.py to turn it off.

Scrapy doc: [ROBOTTXT_OBEY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)

---

**Second:**

You use `di = json.loads(response.text)` which means you expect `JSON` data but this page sends `HTML` and you have to use functions `response.css(...)`, `response.xpath(...)` and `.get()`, `.attrib.get(...)`, etc.

Scrapy doc: [Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

---

Working code:

You can put all code in one file `script.py` and run as `python script.py` without creating project. It will also automatically save results in `test.json` without using `-o test.json`

```
import scrapy
import datetime

class PagesearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'pageSearch'

    def start_requests(self):
        queries = [ 'love']
        for query in queries:
            url = 'https://www.ask.com/web?q='+query
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)
        
        start_pos = response.meta['pos']
        print('start pos:', start_pos)

        dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')    
        
        items = response.css('div.PartialSearchResults-item')
        
        for pos, result in enumerate(items, start_pos+1):
            yield {
                'title':    result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link::text').get().strip(), 
                'snippet':  result.css('p.PartialSearchResults-item-abstract::text').get().strip(), 
                'link':     result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link').attrib.get('href'), 
                'position': pos, 
                'date':     dt,
            }

        # --- after loop ---
        
        next_page = response.css('.PartialWebPagination-next a')
        
        if next_page:
            url = next_page.attrib.get('href')
            print('next_page:', url)  # relative URL
            # use `follow()` to add `https://www.ask.com/` to URL and create absolute URL
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': pos+1})


# --- run without project, and save in file ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'test.json': {'format': 'json'}},
    #'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,  # this stop scraping
})
c.crawl(PagesearchSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this line `User-agent: *Disallow: /web` means that Ask does not allow its data to be scraped? Because I understand that Ask has no problem with scraping.

Comment: line `User-agent: *   Disallow: /web` means that `Ask` doesn't allow to scrape `/web` by any program. But this can't stop program if it really want to scrape it. If you use `ROBOTTXT_OBEY = True` then `scrapy` will respect this information and it will NOT scrape this url. If you use `ROBOTTXT_OBEY = False` then `scrapy` will scrape it.

Comment: So my Ip address cannot be banned by this site if it detects the robot?

Comment: this variable has nothing to do with your IP and detecting bots - it only informs if code has to read file  `/robots.txt` and use rules from this file.